# which formats are supports by imgscalr library?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-resizing, imgscalr

I want to show for users scaled images to reduce internet traffic between client and server.

To resolve my problem I've found library with name `imgscalr`

At [github page](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) write that this library bad support gif.

I couldn't find list of supported formats.
In our application user can load any picture with any extension thus this questin is very actual for me.

Please help or advice another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - imgscalr operates directly on the decoded BufferedImage instances - meaning something (typically ImageIO) has already decoded the file into raw image data and imgscalr itself has no concern of 'file format' -- it's just working on RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it depends on used java version for example for java 7 this library supports following formats:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html